# Fileinfo: finfo_buffer() results differ from finfo_file()

Tags: php, file

I am trying to determine the type of files using PHP's Fileinfo extension (based on libmagic). There is one strange case for Microsoft Outlook message files (mails using the .msg extension). file(1) reports these as application/CDFV2-corrupt. I am not sure why the "-corrupt", but CDFV2 is correct, although not specific: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format

My problem is that when using PHP's `finfo_buffer()`, the type obtained is application/msword. A CDFV2 file could be a Microsoft Word document, but that is not always the case, and it is not the case here. Yet, if I determine type using `finfo_file()`, I get the expected application/CDFV2-corrupt.

The documentation for these functions is not too clear, but if I understand correctly, the following test case should have identical values in its results array, whatever the file contents are, but that is not the case with Outlook mails (for example, with https://dev.tiki.org/dl1120 ). Am I misunderstanding `finfo_buffer()`, or is there a bug?

```
<?php
$object = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$path = 'C:/testCDFV.msg';
$results = array();

{
    $results ['direct'] = $object->file($path);

    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    $results['contentsOO'] = $object->buffer($contents);

    $resource = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $results['contentsProcedural'] = finfo_buffer($resource, $contents);
}

var_dump($results);
?>
```

I did not find a ticket tracking such a bug. The behavior is the same with PHP 5.5.9 on GNU/Linux and on PHP 5.6.30 on Windows. I did not test PHP 7's behavior (if someone who has it could, that would be appreciated).

Comment: I experience the issue with Excel-files in PHP7. I found this bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55691